# Google XML-Sitemap: WP HTTP API Web Request failed: connect() timed out?

Tags: wordpress, xml-sitemap

I did a lot of search, but error remains, when I run `XML-Sitemap` plugin in wordpress, I got this:

> Ping Test
>
> Trying to ping: http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.triffic.cc%2Findex.php%3Fxml_sitemap%3Dparams%3D. The sections below should give you an idea whats going on.
>
> Errors, Warnings, Notices:
>
> WP_DEBUG was set to false somewhere before. You might not see all debug information until you remove this declaration!
>   Notice: WP HTTP API Web Request failed: connect() timed out! in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/sitemap-core.php on line 2052
>   Result (text only):
>
> Result (HTML):

How to solve this problem, any effort will be appreciated.

Version: `Google XML-Sitemap 4.0.8`, `WordPress 4.3.3`

Answer (score 0):

If still worth anything, see the end of `wp-config.php` file you have the `define('WP_DEBUG', false)` so you can change it to `true` for testing.